# Issues reformatting my dataset for TSfresh

Tags: python, pandas

For those unaware, here is the proper format of a data set that can be digested by TSFresh:

```
    id  time    F_x F_y F_z T_x T_y T_z
0   1   0   -1  -1  63  -3  -1  0
1   1   1    0   0  62  -3  -1  0
2   1   2   -1  -1  61  -3  0   0
3   1   3   -1  -1  63  -2  -1  0
4   1   4   -1  -1  63  -3  -1  0
```

And here is my data set right now:

[image]

What I would like is for all of my dates to be the 'time' in the dataframe above and my mutual funds will be the 'id'. My first thought was to use `pd.melt` with the following code:

```
testing2 = pd.melt(testing, id_vars= testing.index, value_vars=testing.columns.values)
```

Which yields the following dataframe:

[image]

I was able to get my `id` and `value` to be correct but the date is not coming in correctly and I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Raw Data

```
AABTX   AACTX   AADTX   AAETX   AAFTX   AAGPX   AAGTX   AAHTX   AAIPX   AALTX   ... VTSMX   VTTHX   VTTVX   VTWNX   VTWSX   VTXVX   WASAX   WBIGX   WMGAX   YAFFX
Date                                                                                    
2012-09-04  -0.552505   -0.590357   -0.617835   -0.590901   -0.568813   -0.527866   -0.562506   -0.554169   -0.534142   -0.553560   ... -0.498664   -0.542211   -0.546897   -0.547675   -0.498821   -0.581834   -0.096870   -0.516713   -0.396338   -0.308581
2012-09-05  -0.552505   -0.593916   -0.620684   -0.593322   -0.571045   -0.530639   -0.564629   -0.556210   -0.532483   -0.555652   ... -0.499373   -0.543793   -0.548980   -0.550324   -0.502974   -0.585566   -0.108832   -0.514231   -0.401808   -0.307566
2012-09-06  -0.501743   -0.551211   -0.577949   -0.554581   -0.533099   -0.489973   -0.528536   -0.521516   -0.464490   -0.522179   ... -0.474196   -0.505818   -0.511480   -0.511913   -0.459360   -0.537058   -0.078529   -0.469567   -0.356951   -0.272033
2012-09-07  -0.486515   -0.536976   -0.563704   -0.540054   -0.521938   -0.479807   -0.517920   -0.511312   -0.429664   -0.509627   ... -0.468522   -0.491578   -0.494813   -0.497344   -0.440669   -0.514670   -0.054606   -0.442271   -0.339445   -0.271018
2012-09-10  -0.501743   -0.547652   -0.575100   -0.552160   -0.533099   -0.490897   -0.526413   -0.519475   -0.446248   -0.520087   ... -0.475969   -0.502654   -0.507313   -0.507940   -0.452092   -0.529596   -0.056998   -0.449715   -0.353668   -0.284216
2012-09-11  -0.486515   -0.536976   -0.566553   -0.542475   -0.524170   -0.478883   -0.520043   -0.513353   -0.413080   -0.511719   ... -0.472068   -0.493160   -0.496897   -0.499993   -0.438592   -0.518402   -0.052213   -0.434827   -0.353668   -0.280155
2012-09-12  -0.486515   -0.533417   -0.560855   -0.537632   -0.519706   -0.476110   -0.515797   -0.509271   -0.393180   -0.507535   ... -0.468522   -0.486831   -0.490647   -0.494695   -0.430285   -0.510939   -0.046631   -0.427383   -0.343821   -0.286246
```

Comment: You say that "id" and "value" are correct after `melt`, and before that you say you want your "Date" index to be the "time" column in your TSFresh example -- is your target output three columns? If so, won't `testing.reset_index().melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='ID', value_name='Value').rename(columns={'Date':'Time'})` work?

Comment: you could use `pd.stack` to get a stacked DataFrame.